# Android where to initialize Crashlytics in a widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, crashlytics

I wanted to know where to initialize Crashlytics in a widget. I know you have to call `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());` but where would I put this in a widget? Inside the WidgetProvider?

Answer (score 1):

Create an application class or put it in your launcher activity. The best way is I think creating class that extends an Application class like :

```
public class MyApp extends Application{

@override
public void onCreate(){
   Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to have an application class or activity. It should be a standalone widget without any activity

Comment: you can write in onStartCommand() or something like that which is called upon creation of views and all.

Comment: I guess I'll do that then